# Angular JS $scope from Partials not working in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Sorry I have searched high and low for HOURS!!!

It is very hard to explain but basically my $scope from introController is appearing in the partial that it is connected to by route, but not appearing in the index.html file which has ng-route. I want to add a header to my index.html containing the name which is stored in $scope.name but I am really having trouble, it's probably something simple but I am absolutely stuck, I think I need somebody else to stare at the code, I've done it all day :(

```js
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('appMod', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'introController',
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/intro.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });

    app.controller('introController', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "";
        $scope.formHide = "";
    });


})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="appMod">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/animation.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular-timer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="content/images/sitelogo.png" class="logo">
        <h2 class="welcomeMessage fade" ng-show="formHide == 'True'">Welcome <span class="fade" ng-show="!name == ''">{{name}}</span><span class="inline fade" ng-hide="name !== ''">Friend</span> <small>(We like to get personal!)</small></h2>
    </div>
</div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller specified with your route is only scoped to the content located in the `ng-view`.  You can read about this in the [Experiments section of this tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

You could create a new controller for your header, say `headerController` and add this controller to your header with `ng-controller="headerController"`.

On a side note, I suggest to use the [controller as syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).  It will allow you to manage different controllers and remember what's where easily.  It also enable you to avoid most, if not all, prototypal inheritance masking primitives issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your `introController` is only bounded to `<div ng-view></div>` for app/partials/intro.html so anything bind to $scope is only visible inside the `ng-view.`

Now instead of binding name with `$scope` bind it with `$rootScope` like 
`$rootScope.name="yourname"` it is available for complete application.

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/xgQ5R4N9ayV9XMCRT0GP?p=preview